# 'wxPython' ID icons not showing

Tags: user-interface, icons, wxpython

I am learning wxPython. I was taught that when you use various id's on your menus such as `ID_EXIT`, `ID_NEW`, `ID_UNDO` etc it would put a name and ICON on the menu. But unfortunately, icons not showing in WINDOWS. And I assume that it works only in linux.

Is there any other way to do this? Where can I find some icon packs to continue my learning in wxpython? As I can't use those id icons, I wanted to set them manually with `SetBitmap`. But as I don't have any icons at all, I also can't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example to add images to your menu items. I have used [SetBitmap()](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/StaticBitmap.html#StaticBitmap.SetBitmap) to add the images to a menu item. Download the Exit-icon.png file from [here](https://db.tt/RrW8yu9N) and put it in the same directory where the script resides.

```
import wx

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        screenWidth = 500
        screenHeight = 400
        screenSize = (screenWidth,screenHeight)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
        myMenuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        quit = wx.MenuItem(file, 101, '&Quit\tCtrl+Q', 'Quit the Application')
        # Adding an image to the quit menu item
        quit.SetBitmap(wx.Image('Exit-icon.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        file.AppendItem(quit)
        file.AppendSeparator()
        myMenuBar.Append(file, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(myMenuBar)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Problem Demo-PSS")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Edit**:
[Mr. wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395984/robindunn) commented regarding the icon packs:

> wxPython also includes a small set of stock icons. See the docs and
>   demos for wx.ArtProvider.

Regarding the icons pack you should prefer to use .png files and you can find a lot of free stuff on the [internet](https://www.google.co.in/#q=icon+packs). There is also a standard size format of the icons depending on the OS. For eg., I got the following table from [here](http://www.visualpharm.com/articles/icon_sizes.html):

```
OS          Icon format Size 

Windows     16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 256x256
Mac OS X    16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, 1024x1024
Linux       16x16, 24x24, 48x48, and 96x96
iOS 6       29x29, 50x50, 57x57, 58x58, 72x72, 100x100, 114x114, 144x144, 1024x1024
iOS 7       29x29, 40x40, 58x58, 60x60, 76x76, 80x80, 120x120, 152x152, 1024x1024
Android     36x36, 48x48, 72x72, 96x96, 512x512
Windows Phone   62x62, 99x99, 173x173, 200x200
```

**Update:** You can find icon packs [here](http://findicons.com) for an example. Use the search option:

Exit icon http://findicons.com/search/exit

Undo icon http://findicons.com/search/undo

Redo icon http://findicons.com/search/redo

Simply click on any icon a new page opens and then click on download png button. Also you can simply rename the icon file even if it is not named a Exit/Undo/Redo. :)

Comment: Your code would help. But can you give a direct link where would I find icons like exit, play, undo/redo, search etc. I have searched a lot in google but in vain. They have a lot of icon packs but none of them contained anything like exit.png, undo.png, redo.png etc...

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks for the specific website. I didn't know about Icon SEARCH ENGINE

Comment: wxPython also includes a small set of stock icons.  See the docs and demos for wx.ArtProvider.

Comment: @RobinDunn Thanks for the suggestion I shall add this to my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In wxPython 4.0.1 (and possibly earlier releases) you do not need to download icons for the basic stuff. Using [zetcode's simple toolbar example](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/) the following line throws an error if 'tnew.png' is not found:

```
toolbar1.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_ANY, '', wx.Bitmap('tnew.png'))
```

however, you can use the built-in icons using [wx.ArtProvider](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ArtProvider.html#wx-artprovider).GetBitmap():

```
icon = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_QUIT)
toolbar1.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, '', icon)  # AddLabelTool raises DeprecationWarning
```

and [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/stock_items.html#stock-id-list) is a list of what is embedded, ART_QUIT is probably not the best replacement 'tnew.png'.